# Html.fromHtml("message.") getting error android

Tags: android

i am getting an error when converting my message into html on run time.
according to my requirement, i am using this code

```
  messageTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml((message2
        ) + "&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;" +
                "&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;"));
```

for some space at runtime.but if message2 contain dot(.) in the last of message its showing as a clickable link so i used like this-

```
  messageTextView.setText(message2+ Html.fromHtml(
        " " + "&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;" +
                "&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;"));
```

but its getting error in some devices.not showing any space at run time.How to resolved this?